# Link para compartir Alpha test y google groups

Tags: android

Estoy intentando agregar testers desde en un grupo de google, ya he registrado exitosamente el grupo (nombre_grupo@googlegroups.com)

No obstante la URL de invitación me marca error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación ya fue publicada dado que si uso "Lista de correos" sin problema deja acceder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente debes tener 2 cosas en cuenta:

- Registrar un grupo de Google existente.
- La url para acceder a pruebas debe ser definida con el package name de la aplicación https://play.google.com/apps/testing/< Package name > esta es la que cargaras en tu navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto al mensaje:

> Todavía no se ha publicado una versión de prueba de esta aplicación o
>   no esta disponible para esta cuenta.

Son 3 causas:

- Es necesario que la versión de prueba tenga un `versionCode` mayor al de el .apk de producción.
- La cuenta con la cual estas firmada en tu navegador y con la cual deseas cargar la url `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/<Package name>` , no esta incluida en el grupo de google que definiste.
- La aplicación aún no esta publicada, recuerda que no es automático.